# Notify Modal forms' parent that it needs to action something

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, modal-dialog

I have a parent form open a modal form which basically allows a user to change the database settings of the application.

When the user clicks the save button on the modal (child) form it saves the Settings object with the new settings but I need to have the Main form check that the database settings are correct.

I currently do this through a function which tries to simply connect to the database and if successful return true, false if this failed. That function I execute within the applications constructor so it runs fine whenever the application is closed and restarted.

I tried the following within the modal form after saving the settings but get a NullReference exception for object myManager.

This is the function which gets the new settings and saves them and then attempts to call the parent forms CheckDatabaseIsSetup() public function to test the db connection.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Save the settings and then hide the Settings window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // TRUE: User indicates that we are to connect using a trusted connection
        // FALSE: User wants to use Integrated security to connect.
        if (rb_UseTrustedConnection.Checked)
        {

            AppSettings.DatabaseName = tb_Trusted_DbName.Text;
            AppSettings.Server = tb_Trusted_Server.Text;
            AppSettings.UseIntergratedSecurity = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AppSettings.DatabaseName = tb_Secure_DbName.Text;
            AppSettings.Server = tb_Secure_Server.Text;
            AppSettings.Username = tb_Secure_Username.Text;
            AppSettings.Password = tb_Secure_Password.Text;
            AppSettings.UseIntergratedSecurity = true;
        }

        try
        {             
            AppSettings.SaveSettings();
            BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain myManager = (BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain)this.ParentForm;
            myManager.CheckDatabaseIsSetup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogAppendWithException(ex);
        }

        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Why not just put the code from CheckDatabaseIsSetup() into some kind of settings manager class and then you can call it from wherever you want.  Code in forms should be UI related.

Comment: Ben, apologies I should have mentioned that the Main Form's function CheckDatabaseIsSetup() calls the databaseutilities class's TestDatabaseConnection which tests the connection. So it is in a seperate object.

Reason I have the call in the main function is to allow the main form to open the database setup form if the connection fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use the Owner property in the modal form rather than the ParentForm property as follows:

```
BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain myManager = (BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain)this.Owner;
```

The Owner property defines the actual relationship between the owned(modal) form and the parent(owner) form.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to define an event in child form and handle this event in main form 
and when ever you raise this event in child form mainform can does its own job

Answer (score 1):

```
BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain myManager = (BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain)this.ParentForm;
```

You can check the above line whether `ParentForm` is of Type/can cast to `BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain`. I presume the case wasn't successful hence return `null`

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually do this by using object intercommunication such as provided with my [Emesary](http://emesary.codeplex.com/) library; The design is to use notifications in such a way that the request is sent and handled by anything that knows it needs to process these notifications, so for example it's easy to add in extra event handlers that are disconnected.

In which case the code for checking the database settings would become:

```
if (ReceiptStatus.OK == 
    GlobalNotifier.NotifyAll(new CheckDatabaseIsSetupNotification(tb_Secure_DbName.Text,
                             tb_Secure_Server.Text,
                             tb_Secure_Username.Text,
                             tb_Secure_Password.Text,
                             true))
{
     // do something.
}
```

To make this work you'd need to implement IReceiver in BushBreaksLodgeManagerMain and in the constructor call

```
    GlobalTransmitter.Register(this);
```

then implement the interface receive:

```
public ReceiptStatus Receive(INotification _message)
{
    if (_message is CheckDatabaseIsSetupNotification)
    {
         var message = _message as CheckDatabaseIsSetupNotification;
         if (connect_to(message.DatabaseName, message.Server, Message.Username, message.Password, message.UseIntergratedSecurity))
            return ReceiptStatus.OK;
         else
            return ReceiptStatus.Fail;
    }
    return ReceiptStatus.NotProcessed;
}
```

You can do this using Windows events - but this way is clearer and allows inter operation with objects that don't necessarily have windows.